# Apps killed by android:Redmi S3

Tags: applications, whatsapp-messenger, troubleshooting, redmi

Phone model : Redmi s2
Ram : 3 GB

My phone is killing apps when more than one app is running.

Even when messaging apps are running like messenger. I can't use messenger when other apps are in background.

Task manager always shows 1.3-1.5 GB free memory (So, I don't think that this is because of low memory). I tried with "no restriction" options in battery saver but it doesn't help.

Is there any way of getting out of this?

Comment: Some phone manufacturer implement a very aggressive battery saving (called "battery optimization") and therefore apps are killed or suspended. May be this is also the source of your problems. Check the battery options in settings.

Comment: See: https://dontkillmyapp.com/xiaomi

Comment: I tried with "no restriction" options in battery saver... But remains same 

Comment: In developers option check if "Background process limit" is set to default or standard limit. If it is 1,2 or 3 processes increase it. And uncheck the "Don't keep activities" if checked.

Comment: In developer options 'Background process limit' already in standard and i have tried with 1,2 or 3. Don't keep activity is unchecked because i didn't use it.